# ASP.Net Core - Policy and Cookie Authentication Reason on Forbidden Page

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using CookieAuthentication & Policy to check the users and redirect to Account/Forbidden url when it fails... On the page, I want to display some details.. such as

- The page they tried to access
- Reason of the Fail
- And other debug info...

There are 6 types of user levels in my app.
At the moment, it does redirect the users to Forbidden page when it fails to meet the UserRole... but I couldn't trace which page they were trying to access before the Forbidden occured...

ConfigureServices() in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});
```

Configure() in Startup.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

My Controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: It seems there is no easy way(i couldn't find any way) to capture forbidden result in the mvc pipeline. An alternative  way may be to use `UseStatusCodePages` and handle 403 status code but it is out of mvc context and you can only use  HttpContext properties with this way(like path).

Comment: The ReturnUrl value / querystring on the Forbidden page is always blank - %2f...  If MVC engine could populates that one, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I reviewed source code, the cookie authentication middleware sends return url to access denied page(https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L373). Are you sure it is empty?

Comment: I copied your code and I can confirm that returnUrl is NOT empty. So the issue might be somewhere else. Did you try `var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();` ?

Comment: Yeah, You guys are right.  Normally, it puts the ReturnURL on the forbidden page.  I am seeing %2F because that user was trying to access the Home/Default Page.  I still think it would be handy to detect which policy is preventing the users from an access.